# How to convert char to string in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a string variable `s`, and I have a map data structure(with string keys) `m`.

I want to check if each letter in `s` is present in `m`, so I do `m.containsKey(s[i])`.

Since, map containsKey function expects string argument, I get the following error:

```
invalid conversion from char to const char*
```

Any ideas, on how to convert a char to a string data-type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the substring instead of indexing.

```
s.substr(i, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string s="";
char a;

s+=a;

s is now a string of char a
```

Answer (score 3):

Another method is :

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
stringstream ss;
string s;
char c = 'a';
ss << c;
ss >> s;
```

Comment: This just might be in the running for the most expensive way to convert a character to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `s.substr(i, 1)`. But if you have only `char`s in your map, I like the answer above better.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "test";
anyFunction(str[x]);
```

The [ ] operator provides you with a char and if any function expects string, then surely an error will occur. But you can always try this sneaky conversion:

```
string str = "test";
char c = str[x];
string temp = c;
anyFunction(temp);
```